# Set membership query for "fuzzy" set

Tags: algorithm, hash, set

I have a set `Sx` of integers over which I want to answer set membership queries in as little space as possible. (edited to make more clear in response to Niklas' comment)

However, I am allowed some "fuzziness" in the numbers, i.e., it is ok if instead of a number `x` in `Sx`, I store any other number `y` in the range `[x-k, x+k]`. Here `k` is a given "fuzziness" constant.

Now, we have modified the set `Sx` to another set `Sy` formed by all the `y` values, which are fuzzed versions of `x` values. Now, I will like to have a data structure that can answer set membership queries over `Sy`, possibly with some error probability `e` (note that the elements in `Sx` are no longer relevant to the set membership query, it is ok even if all the elements in `Sx` are changed to different values).

A simple answer would be to create a bloom filter consisting of all elements in `Sx`, which will consume `O(|Sx|log(1/e))`. I will like to know if this bound can be improved upon in my specific scenario.

In practice, the number `k` is around 3, while the numbers in set `S` are spaced by around 30.

Comment: Can you just round to the nearest multiple of *2k + 1*? That would save you a factor of *2k + 1* space

Comment: I can't see your logic. Can you please elaborate?

Comment: In every interval `[x-k, x+k]` there will be a multiple of `2k+1`. So you can just replace `x` with that multiple. Then you can divide all your numbers by `2k+1` to store them more compactly. Or maybe I didn't get your question.

Comment: Yeah I think my question was not clear. I am not actually interested in storing these numbers but only in answering set membership queries over the modified numbers, i.e., given any new number `n`, I will like to know whether `n` is in `Sy` or not. Bloom filters don't actually store the elements. I am not sure how rounding numbers to multiples of `2k+1` helps in that.

Comment: You say your numbers are an average of 30 away from each other. Dividing by 7 would get this down to 4 or so. So even a simple bit set would probably use less space than your bloom filter, so why not use that? Asymptotically-wise something like a sorted array take O(|Sx|) bits of space, so maybe you need to stay away from Big-O here to make your goal clearer.

Comment: You also don't mention whether you need online insertion or just one-time preprocessing and then multiple queries

Comment: One time preprocessing and multiple queries.

Comment: I see. That is an interesting method. I will try to see how that performs. Any other ideas?

Comment: There's lots of ideas in the area of [succinct data structures](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Succinct_data_structure) One thing I would try in your situation is to go with a bitset and try to compress it some more. For example look at windows of 32 bits at once. Since you seem to assume a certain distribution of your numbers (spaced X away from each other), lots of possible ways to fill these 32 bits will be very unlikely. You can just pretend those don't happen at all and use only k bits to store the 32 bit window. You have a certain probability of failure due to unlikely patterns occuring

Comment: You can also use various generic compression methods. It's all a matter of how much query time you can sacrifice